# Linux pipe finished reading but want to discard rest

Tags: python, linux, unix, pipe, subprocess

I have a piece of code that is starting a process then reading from stdout to see if it has loaded OK.

After that, I'd ideally like to redirect the output to `/dev/null` or something that discards it.  I was (A) what is the best practice in this situation and (B) what will happen to the writing process if the pipe becomes full?  Will it ever block when the pipe becomes full and is not being read/cleared?

If the aim is to redirect to `/dev/null` would it be possible to show me how to to this with python and `subprocess.Popen`?

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(command, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
while True:
    if init_string in proc.stderr.readline():
        break;

proc.stderr.redirect ??
```

Comment: You could execute the script and discard its output `python firstprogram.py > /dev/null`

Comment: I need to discard after reading a little bit first though.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there is no way to close and reopen file descriptors of a child process after it has started executing. And yes, there is a limited buffer in the OS, so if you don't consume anything from the pipe, eventually the child process will block. That means you'll just have to keep reading from the pipe until it's closed from the write end.

If you want your program to continue doing something useful in the meantime, consider moving the data-consuming part to a separate thread (untested):

```
def read_all_from_pipe(pipe):
  for line in pipe: # assuming it's line-based
    pass

Thread(lambda: read_all_from_pipe(proc.stderr)).start()
```

There may be other ways to solve your problem, though. Why do you need to wait for some particular output in the first place? Shouldn't the child just die with a nonzero exit code if it didn't "load OK"? Can you instead check that the child is doing what it should, rather than that it's printing some arbitrary output?

Comment: Thanks! I was afraid that would be the case. I will probably spin up a reader thread like you suggest, it just seemed wasteful.

Comment: The other way to do it would be to redirect to a file, and then have my parent application read that file?

Comment: Unless there is a way to make a pipe that splits, and then have part of it closed off?

Comment: @John you might consider `tee`

Comment: @John: an easy way to discard the rest of the output: `collections.deque(proc.stderr, maxlen=0)`.

Answer (score -2):

If you would like to discard all the output:

`python your_script.py > /dev/null`

However, if you want to do it from Python you can use:

```
import sys
sys.stdout = open('file', 'w')
print 'this goes to file'
```

Everytime you print, the standard output has been redirected to the file "file", change that to /dev/null or any file you want and you will obtain the wanted results.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to redirect the stderr AFTER reading from it for a while, not immediately.  I'm concerned that not reading from it will fill the buffer after a while and block the calling process when it tries to write into it.

Comment: The script that starts the process reads from the process' `stderr`.  It reads a few init messages to check a few things happened, then leaves the process open or closes it.  At this point I want to redirect the output so that the process writing to `stderr` doesn't push to a buffer that is never read.